# OSX 10.9.2 - Cant access some site on Wifi (namely github.com)

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, dns

I started experiencing this issue a while ago, probably not too long after `OSX 10.9.1 update` (not sure about this but would make sense), while it was working just fine before.

I basically cannot access github.com at all, only when on WIFI. 
I also realized I cannot access Facebook either

Ethernet connection works correctly. I am using that machine 99% of the time at work, and I naturally put the blame on the Proxy used here, but then I brought it home and experienced the same issue from my wifi network.

My PC can access Github without problems over the same network. Colleagues can access Github over the same Wifi network as well.

The Error I am getting: "This webpage is not available / Unable to Connect"

I've tried all the following so far:

- Tried all available browsers, as well as from a VM (Virtual Box running Win8, configured in NAT).
- Rebooting, resetting PRAM
- Deleting the location profile (in network settings) and recreated it
- Enabled/Disabled Proxy settings
- Tethered connection from iPhone (it will just hang on "resolving host"
- Tried Different DNS (Google: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)
- Traceroute will throw: `traceroute: bind: Can't assign requested address`
- Host file is clean

I literally don't know what to try next and try to isolate the problem

Being a Javascript developer, I don't need to say that it is hindering my work quite a bit;

---

Looks like some VPN config MIGHT be in cause here too:
I have `Juniper Network Connect` installed to connect to a Client's VPN

When I am connected to the Client's VPN, I *can* access Facebook.com, but not Github.com

---

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Edit:

dig github.com output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> github.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41616
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     20  IN  A   192.30.252.130

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed May  7 15:34:52 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

---

Edit2: Fired Console App and got this output - probably the most helpful piece of info I've got:

```
2014-05-07 3:50:47.593 PM Google Chrome Helper[14672]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
2014-05-07 3:50:47.593 PM Google Chrome Helper[14672]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
2014-05-07 3:50:47.601 PM Google Chrome Helper[14672]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
2014-05-07 3:50:47.876 PM Google Chrome Helper[14673]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd. : LSXPCClient.cp #426 ___ZN26LSClientToServerConnection21setupServerConnectionEiPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke() q=com.apple.main-thread
2014-05-07 3:50:47.877 PM Google Chrome Helper[14673]: Process unable to create connection because the sandbox denied the right to lookup com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd and so this process cannot talk to launchservicesd.
2014-05-07 3:50:47.882 PM Google Chrome Helper[14673]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1100)
```

---

Edit 3:
I tried killing the `launchservicesd` process, which brought the machine to an unbearable crawl (it even had trouble registering click events O_o) so I shutdown and restarted and Lo! It now works O_O I am not sure I should mark this question as resolved as I feel we didn't find a cause/real fix yet, but for now things are fine. The question now is "until when"... Thanks for your help all

Comment: First step.  Have you updated the VPN client since the Heartbleed exploit was annouced.  The built-in Windows Juniper VPN client was recently patched.

Comment: I also see those Google Chrome Helper errors but can load github.com and Facebook.com with no problems (I did not log in on either site though).  Have you also tried with Safari and/or Firefox?

Comment: Strange that when you run dig it does not show the authority section.  Did you also try to ping and traceroute (you can use the Network Utiltiy for that)?

Comment: Traceroute output is in the main post
And yes, tried different browsers etc

That said, I tried killing the `launchservicesd` process, which brought the machine to an unbearable crawl (it even had trouble registering click events O_o) so I shutdown and restarted and Lo! It now works O_O I am not sure I should mark this question as resolved as I feel we didn't find a cause/real fix yey, but for now things are fine. The question now is "until when"...

Thakns for your help all

Answer (score 0):

You want to start by making sure DNS is working correctly.  In Terminal, type

```
dig github.com
```

The part you are looking for should look something like this:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     12  IN  A   192.30.252.131

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
github.com.     86382   IN  NS  ns2.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86382   IN  NS  ns3.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86382   IN  NS  ns4.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86382   IN  NS  ns1.p16.dynect.net.
```

Then you would want to try ping and traceroute, and compare the results of all three commands to other sites that are working properly.

Comment: hi, not sure what Dig is for or how to interpret this data, but I added the output in the original question

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with the OSX tcpip stack. Look and see if a socket bound to github is hanging around. You can use the `netstat` command.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5551686?tstart=0

Comment: Hi, there doesn't seem to be anything relating to Github in netstat's output, either by IP or domain - I am not very well versed in sockets and internal working of it all. Would there be something else to look for?

Comment: Not sure. `bind: can't assign requested address` means that bind() was unable to successfully link to the local socket endpoint requested. That is usually because the socket endpoint is in use or has not yet been released after being closed by another program. Netstat tells you the status of sockets, so something should show up if this is a problem with a socket being somehow in use.